# Append options in a select

Tags: jquery, ajax, append

What is wrong with this part of js code ?

I want to append some data in my select.

```
$.each(data.souscommande, function (index, value) {
    $('#cfrnscmdid').append($('<option/>', {
        value: value.producteurid,
        text: value.producteurnom
    }).prop('selected', data.scmdtrp == value.nom));
});
```

I want to delete the function selected but if i do i will have a problem with  }); .

Comment: What does AJAX have to do with this?

Comment: Looks like you're missing a closing paren (to close the `append` function call), but other than that, the snippet works fine (if my assumptions on what you aren't showing us are correct): http://jsfiddle.net/YFDCC/

Comment: Sorry i was not clear (because of my english), i made some modification. I want to use this fucntion but without "selected".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $('#cfrnscmdid').append($('<option>', {
     value: data.id
 }).text(data.nom));
```